# Unable to delete Entity with Many to Many related objects using SF2 Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, many-to-many, sylius

I have a activity planning system and i'm facing an issue. My main item is called AircrewAvailability and is linked to a Period item through a Many To Many relation (the Period must stay agnostic so it can be used by other entities without storing their ids).

This availability is displayed on a FullCalendar system : Each period of each availability is an event on the FullCalendar. When clicking on the FullCalendar, we access to the CRUD form.

Create and Edit work both fine, but Delete is troublesome. When i try to remove an Availability, the ORM tries to delete the Period but does not touch to the relation table (aircrew_availability_period), so I get an Integrity constraint violation (which makes perfect sense).

Here are my mappings :

Availability entity :

```
<entity name="Mouke\Component\Availability\Model\AircrewAvailability" table="TBL_aircrew_availability">
    <id name="id" length="40">
        <generator strategy="CUSTOM"/>
        <custom-id-generator class="Mouke\Component\Resource\Doctrine\ORM\Id\Sha1IdGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-many target-entity="Mouke\Component\Application\Model\PeriodInterface" field="periods" orphan-removal="true" fetch="EAGER">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-all/>
        </cascade>
        <join-table name="aircrew_availability_period">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="aircrew_availability_id"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="period_id"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
        <gedmo:versioned/>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

Period entity :

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping">

<entity name="Mouke\Component\Application\Model\Period" table="TBL_period">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="string" length="40">
        <generator strategy="CUSTOM"/>
        <custom-id-generator class="Mouke\Component\Resource\Doctrine\ORM\Id\Sha1IdGenerator"/>
    </id>
    <field name="startedAt" column="started_at" type="datetime"/>
    <field name="endedAt" column="ended_at" type="datetime"/>
</entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

About my Forms, here the concerned part :

Availability form :

```
$builder->add('periods', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PeriodType::class,
            'label' => 'Periods',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'ajax-collection section-no-padding',
            ],
        ]);
```

Period form :

```
$builder
        ->add('startedAt', DateTimePickerType::class, [
            'label' => 'model.started_at',
            'model_timezone' => $options['model_timezone'],
        ])
        ->add('endedAt', DateTimePickerType::class, [
            'label' => 'model.ended_at',
            'model_timezone' => $options['model_timezone'],
        ]);
```

The tricky part : I can delete a period from an availability, no problem. But if an availability has no period, it is not displayed in my calendar so you can't edit it anymore. Not only "ghost entity" may have side effects that I don't want to deal with, but also it isn't user friendly to "delete periods" to delete the whole availability, especially when you have a huge "Delete" button in the bottom of the form.

Any idea on the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed the `on-delete="CASCADE"` notation :

```
<join-table name="aircrew_availability_period">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="aircrew_availability_id" on-delete="CASCADE"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="period_id" on-delete="CASCADE"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
```